# org-mode: How do I insert correctly escaped text using elisp?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to insert some code using elisp into org-babel source blocks. This needs some escaping, such as replacing `*` with `,*`. Is there a builtin insert function that handles these escape rules automatically?

An example of `,*`:

```
#+begin_src jupyter-python
a(
  ,**kwargs,
)
#+end_src
```

I am currently manually doing:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "^\\(\s*\\)\\*" "\\1,*" formatted-code)
```

But I prefer to use some org-mode API rather than my own ad-hock implementation.

Comment: I found the answer: `org-escape-code-in-string`.

Comment: You should provide this (with more details - e.g. the doc string of the function, and the related -region function) as an answer. YOu can even accept your own answert (after a waiting period).